# How to retrieve a column from a database using a foreign key relationship?

Tags: php, symfony1, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, propel

I have **user** table which stores all his info and I also created a table called **user_education** through schema.yml [**uid** column in this table refers to uid of **user** table]. Model classes have been created using Symfony. I'm able to access all columns of **user** table. E.g. **sf_user->getUser()->getUsername();**.

User model class also has a method, **getUserEducations()**. I need to access a column called **coursename** of user_education table, but am unable to do so. Currently, I'm trying [ **sf_user->getUser()->getUserEducations()->getCoursename();** ] But I'm getting the whole array of records. I can't retrieve a single column by that array.

How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
// get the first tuple
$sf_user->getUser()->getUserEducations()->getFirst()->getCoursename();
```

or

```
// get the last tuple
$sf_user->getUser()->getUserEducations()->getLast()->getCoursename();
```

The proper way (if the user has many educations) is to iterate between the instances:

```
foreach($sf_user->getUser()->getUserEducations() as $education){
    //do something with like
    echo $education->getCoursename();
}
```